# Using regular expressions in vi

Tags: regex, vi

When I write a blog entry in Google blogger then a lot of entries like shown as below are getting inserted in HTML (not sure why).

```
<span id="textmarked_8" name="textmarker_9" style="background-color: yellow;"></span>
```

How I do I remove them? Note the numbers 8 and 9 have to be replaced by some regular expression. I am looking for a command in vi or some other easy command. BTW, I am using Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use an HTML-parser not a regex (see [past answers](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) on this subject).

However if the XML has completely predictable content and formatting you can get away with something like

```
:%s/<span[^>]*><\/span>//
```

(untested)
The important point here is that it tests for an empty span element that happens to be all on the same line. You could add a caret (^) at the start if the unwanted span elements always start at the beginning of a new line.

If you want to match `id="textmarked_[0-9]*` you can do that, I doubt it is necessary. Any empty span element probably serves no useful purpose regardless of it's attributes. The only exception I can think of is if some javascript later populates those elements.

Comment: @PraveenSripati: Good, I'm glad it helped. Do read the linked article though - this bad habit (using regex on HTML) will bite back viciously sooner or later.